# Minimal elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A$ be the set $A = \{1,2,3,...,20\}$.
$R$ is the relation over $A$ such that $xRy$ iff $y/x = 2^i$, $i$ is natural including $0$.
I am supposed to find the minimal and maximal elements in relation to $R$.
Does that mean the elements are members of $A$ or members of $R$?
The elements of $R$ are pairs that their divisions yield $1,2,4,8,16 \ldots$
But I am confused as to whether I am searching for pairs in $R$ or numbers in $A$.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for numbers in $A$. This relation is actually a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) on $A$.

The minimal elements are all the elements $x\in A$ such that there is no $y\neq x$ with $yRx$ (nothing "smaller").

The maximal elements are all the elements $x\in A$ such that there is no $y\neq x$ with $xRy$ (nothing "larger").

In both cases there may be more than one such element. For example, if you only took the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the same relation, we have $1R2$, $2R4$, $1R4$ (and every element is related to itself). This means the minimum elements are $1$ and $3$, whereas the maximal elements are $4$ and $3$.

Comment: thank you very much! so minimal elements are 1,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20. I get the rule but not the intuition "nothing smaller", "nothing bigger"

Comment: @eventhorizon02 those aren't all minimal, for example $10$ isn't because $5R10$. Partial orders are normally written as $\preceq$ or similar, not $R$, which makes it easier to see why this definition makes sense.

Comment: yes, made a mistake forgot to add to ⪯ a few pairs.I think it should be then 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,14,15,17,19. and for maximal 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

Comment: What about $11$ and $12$ for maximal elements?

Comment: yeah, those too

Answer (score 1):

The relation $R$ can be shown to be a partial order. You must find the least and greatest elements of $A$ according to this ordering relation.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for members of $A$.

$a \in A$ is maximal, whenever $aRa'$ implies $a'=a$.

$a \in A$ is minimal, whenever $a'Ra$ implies $a'=a$.